# How to access to a specific page in an Ionic app from a Firebase Dynamic Link?

Tags: firebase, ionic4, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on an Ionic 4 App with firebase. I want to add a functionality to share a specific profile from the App. I have a button to share a dynamic link to Facebook or WhatsApp, but when you click in this Dynamic Link, you open the App in the Main Page. How can I configure the links to open the User Profile Page in the App?

Comment: Bump. #metoo Anyone?